# VS Code Debugger doesn't work - Error processing "breakpointLocations": Error: Script not found

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, javascript-debugger

Debugger doesn't work on vue application(javascript). I put the breakpoints in the component part, but it doesn't work

launch.json: (for Debugger for Chrome)

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "vuejs: chrome",
      "url": "http://localhost:8080",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/src",
      "breakOnLoad": true,
      "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
        "webpack:///src/*": "${webRoot}/*"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

terminal:

```
Error processing "breakpointLocations": Error: Script not found
    at Client.processMessage (/home/user/.vscode/extensions/msjsdiag.debugger-for-chrome-4.12.8/node_modules/noice-json-rpc/lib/noice-json-rpc.js:66:36)
    at LoggingSocket.<anonymous> (/home/user/.vscode/extensions/msjsdiag.debugger-for-chrome-4.12.8/node_modules/noice-json-rpc/lib/noice-json-rpc.js:42:48)
    at LoggingSocket.emit (events.js:208:15)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (/home/user/.vscode/extensions/msjsdiag.debugger-for-chrome-4.12.8/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:789:20)
    at Receiver.emit (events.js:203:13)
    at Receiver.dataMessage (/home/user/.vscode/extensions/msjsdiag.debugger-for-chrome-4.12.8/node_modules/ws/lib/receiver.js:422:14)
    at /home/user/.vscode/extensions/msjsdiag.debugger-for-chrome-4.12.8/node_modules/ws/lib/receiver.js:379:23
    at /home/user/.vscode/extensions/msjsdiag.debugger-for-chrome-4.12.8/node_modules/ws/lib/permessage-deflate.js:298:9
    at /home/user/.vscode/extensions/msjsdiag.debugger-for-chrome-4.12.8/node_modules/ws/lib/permessage-deflate.js:376:7
    at afterWrite (_stream_writable.js:484:3)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited launch.json:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "vuejs: chrome",
      "port": 9222,
      // "url": "http://localhost:8080",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/src",
      "urlFilter": "http://localhost:8080/*"
      /*"breakOnLoad": true,
      "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
        "webpack:///src/*": "${webRoot}/*"
      }*/
    }
  ]
}
```

and open in browser new tab - about:blank, after click on it in CALL STACK row, and open localhost:8080 in this(about:blank) tab